# Proper looping construct using Arrays and List

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop

In this simple example, i want to create a String array populated with each person's first and last in my DB. I know i am missing something very obvious as i keep overriding `i` in the following looping method. A second eye would certainly help.

```
    /**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String[] buildFullNameContainer(){

    List<Person> allPeople = Person.findAllPeople();
    String[] peopleContainer = new String[] {""};
    String fullName = "";



        for (int i = 0; i < peopleContainer.length; i++) {
            for (Person person : allPeople) {
                fullName = person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();  
                peopleContainer[i] = fullName; 

            }
        }
    return peopleContainer;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong?  Does something not work?

Comment: There is only one value when i loop through the String array after calling this method

Comment: @Warz: How would you expect there to ever be more than one element? You're creating an array with one element to start with, and arrays never expand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
String[] peopleContainer = new String[] {""};
```

with

```
String[] peopleContainer = new String[allPeople.size()];
```

---

Also, edit your loop as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < peopleContainer.length; i++)
{
    Person person = allPeople.get(i);
    fullName = person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();  
    peopleContainer[i] = fullName;  
}
```

Comment: if i remove the outter for loop, how can i reference 'i' as it does not exist

Comment: Initialize an `int i` at the beginning. In the `peopleContainer[i] = fullName;` line, change the `i` to a `i++`.

Comment: Best answer as it gets rid of the unnecessary inner for-loop. will accept in a few

Answer (score 4):

Your array always has a single element - you should create it to be the same length as your list. Additionally, you've got two nested loops for no reason, and I see no point in the `fullName` variable. Here's the code I'd use:

```
String[] peopleContainer = new String[allPeople.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < peopleContainer.length; i++) {
    Person person = allPeople.get(i);
    peopleContainer[i] = person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this needs to be changed from:

```
String[] peopleContainer = new String[] {""};
```

To:

```
String[] peopleContainer = new String[allPeople.size()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over your result array, instead of your source data collection.  You have to size the array correctly first, then loop over the size of either the array or the list.  No need for a nested for.

```
public String[] buildFullNameContainer(){

    List<Person> allPeople = Person.findAllPeople();
    String[] peopleContainer = new String[allPeople.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleContainer.length; i++) {
        Person person = allPeople.get(i);
        String fullName = person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();  
        peopleContainer[i] = fullName; 
    }
return peopleContainer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
    List<Person> allPeople = Person.findAllPeople();
    String[] peopleContainer = new String[allPeople.size()];

    for (int i=0;i < allPeople.size();i++;) {
          Person person=allPeople.get(i);
          fullName = person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();  
          peopleContainer[i] = fullName; 
    }
```